# Grails passing variables from gsp to controller

Tags: variables, grails, view, controller

i am relatively new to Grails so excuse me if my Problem is an easy to solve one or not.

Im developing a small WepApplication and have a problem with variables i create in my gsp.

Im creating my variable with <% ArrayList kategorie= new ArrayList() %> to use in a later  method like this:

```
    <g:set var="iterate2" value="${0}" />
    <g:while test="${iterate2<kategorie.size }">

        <h3>
            <% println kategorie.get(iterate2) %>
        </h3>
        <div>
            <p>
                <% println kategoriebesch.get(iterate2) %>
            </p>

            <form>

                <g:actionSubmit value="weiter" action="weiter" />

            </form>


        </div>
        <% iterate2++ %>
    </g:while>
```

Now i do want to pass the variable kategorie to my controller but i can't seem to figure out how to do that.

I also tried creating a static variable within the controller and then changing the value of this variable within the view but that doesn't seem to work either.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Store the value in an input hidden

```
<g:each in="${kategorie}" var="kat" status="i">
    <h3>
        ${kat}
    </h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            ${kategoriebesch[i]}
        </p>
        <form action="weiter">
            <input type="hidden" name="kategorie" value="${kat}" />
            <input type="submit" value="weiter" />
        </form>
    </div>
</g:each>
```